# PowerShell Script to execute a console application

Tags: powershell

Can you please let me know how to run an exe or console application through a powershell script in SharePoint 2010.

Comment: This question doesn't even make any sense. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [Start-Process](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347667.aspx)

For example, I have used it to run an installer

```
Start-Process -FilePath ".\Scripts\Prerequisites\FilterPack\FilterPack64bit.exe" -ArgumentList /passive, /norestart -Wait
```